# Format geom_text label doesn't work when using aes_string

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the dot function to format text labels in a plot created with `ggplot2`. This works fine when using `aes`, but doesn't work like expected when using `aes_string`. Is there a workaround to make it work with `aes_string`?

```
require(ggplot2)

# Define the format function
dot <- function(x, ...) { 
  format(x, ..., big.mark = ".", scientific = FALSE, trim = TRUE)
}

# Create dummy data
df <- data.frame(cbind(levels(iris$Species),c(10000000000,200000,30000)))
df$X2 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$X2))

# Works with aes   
ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_bar(aes(Species,Sepal.Width),stat="identity") +     
  geom_text(data=df,aes(x=factor(X1),y=180,label=dot(X2)))


# Doesn't work with aes_string
ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_bar(aes(Species,Sepal.Width),stat="identity") +
  geom_text(data=df,aes_string(x="X1",y=180,label=dot("X2")))
```

Comment: I think the easiest thing would be to simply apply `dot` outside of ggplot, creating a new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than just quote "X2", you must quote the whole expression

```
ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_bar(aes(Species, Sepal.Width), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(data=df, aes_string(x="X1", y =180, label = "dot(X2)"))
```

If you wanted to specify variable names via a character vector, you would use `paste()` to build that expression.

Comment: Arh, that's the way to do it! Perhaps you should use `aes_string` and not  `aes_foo` to have actual runable code?

Comment: Thanks @AEBilgrau I was testing some code to see what `aes_string` actually did and forgot to take that test function out.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a string constant to `dot` and `dot("X2")` returns `"X2"`. So you're basically giving `aes_string` the argument `label = "X2"`.

I got this to work

```
ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_bar(aes(Species, Sepal.Width), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(data=df, aes_string(x="X1", y =180, label = deparse(dot(df$X2))))
```

[image: Imgur]

### Edit

As suggested by MrFlick, you could also use `df[,"X2"]` if you need to pass the column name as a string. I.e.

```
ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_bar(aes(Species, Sepal.Width), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(data=df, aes_string(x="X1", y =180, label = deparse(dot(df[,"X2"]))))
```

Comment: In order to specify "X2" as a string, you could use `aes_string(x="X1", y =180, label = deparse(dot(df[,"X2"]))))`

Answer (score 2):

As implied by my comment, I dislike relying on `deparse` or other evaluation tricks unless I have to:

```
col <- "X2"
new_col <- paste0(col,"_dot")
df[,new_col] <- dot(df[,col])
ggplot(iris) + 
    geom_bar(aes(Species,Sepal.Width),stat="identity") + 
    geom_text(data=df,aes_string(x="X1",y=180,label=new_col))
```

I presented this version as if we were writing code in a function and had received the `"X2"` as an argument.